# AngularJS directive parameter "ctrls"

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I see a link function in a directive in Angular like so:

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrls) {

  var ngModelCtrl = ctrls[0],
      invalidInputController = ctrls[1];

  // ...
}
```

Can someone help me understand where the controllers in the `ctrl` parameter are coming from?

**Edit:** the directive has an angular `require` property specifying two other directives by name like so:

```
require: ['ngModel', '?numberFormatterPreventInvalidInput'],
```

I suspect they come from there.

Comment: Documentation can https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Typically they come from the `require` part of a directive, which is either a string or an array of controllers.

```
['^something', '^another']
```

Within `link` they are accessed by `ctrl[0]` and `ctrl[1]`.

Also from the documentation:

> The basic difference *(between controller and link)* is that **controller can expose an API, and link
>   functions can interact with controllers using require**.
>
> Best Practice: use controller when you want to expose an API to other
>   directives. Otherwise use link.

Answer (score 1):

if in your directive is written

```
  require:["ngModel","^directiveTwo"]
```

than ngModel , directiveTwo are names of directives and directiveTwo has to be a parent directive

```
  link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrls) {

   var ngModelCtrl = ctrls[0],
     controllerOfDirectiveTwo = ctrls[1];

   // ...
}
```

ctrls the last parameter isthe array of the controller of the directives defined by require  so for ngModel  this :https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController for your directives defined by the  controller:  in your directive